# Convert EBNF to Bison

Tags: bison, ebnf

I have this piece of EBNF grammar that I'd like to convert to Bison syntax.

```
E ::= {S [`;´]} [L [`;´]]
```

I don't have much experience with grammars but I think I managed to figure out that there are some optional parts and some repetition.

My attempt:

```
E:      S semiColOp E lOp semiColOp
;
semiColOp:  /* No Action*/ 
        | semiCol//';' 
;

lOp:        /* No Action*/ 
        | laststat   
;
```

I can't test this atm so it'd be nice to get some input from you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
program   : statements
          | statements last opt_semi
          ;

statements: /* empty */
          | statements statement opt_semi
          ;

opt_semi  : /* empty */
          | ';'
          ;
```

where `program` corresponds to `E`; `statement` to `S` and `last` to `L`.